# text auto font size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-size

I have a div tag for a title, as below, it may be multi lined and I would like the text to be as big as possible to fit neatly in the box. Thanks for any ideas.

```
<div id="main" style="width:700px; height:165px; float:left; font-size:50px; text-align:center; font-family:Chiller;"><?php echo $title ?></div>
```

Comment: This has got to be a duplicate of some other question...

Comment: You should use the new HTML5 header element, and inside it you should have an h1 element. I don't understand your question. Can you describe it a little more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't code it up for you, but I'm sure you could do it with javascript or jQuery.  You'd want to set the overflow property of the div you have coded there.  And you'd want to create a separate div for the title text inside the div that you already have.  Then with javascript you can check to see if the height of the inner div is greater than the height of the outer div.  I haven't tried it, but something like this:

```
<div id="main" style="width:700px; height:165px; float:left; font-size:50px; text-align:center; font-family:Chiller; overflow:hidden;">
    <div id="title"> 
        <?php echo $title ?> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in the javascript you just check to see if the height or width of title is greater than the height or width of main.  If it is, you decrease the font size and check again until it fits.  I would probably hide the title div until I get the right font size.

This article also might help: http://objectmix.com/javascript/112045-check-overflow-div.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to test this but I found these two links that might help you out:

[auto resize text (font size) when resizing window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989950/auto-resize-text-font-size-when-resizing-window)

and

http://icodesnip.com/snippet/jquery/jquery-automatic-text-resize