# How can I stop IE11 wrapping the rightmost nav item on to another line?

Tags: html, css

IE11 is wrapping the rightmost of my four nav items to the next line, when all four together are supposed to fit on one line and have a combined width of 320px. How can I stop this?

***HTML***

```
<body>
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Four</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

***CSS***

```
html, body, div, span, nav {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        border:0;
            width: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav{
    display: block;
}
    #nav ul {
        text-align: justify;
        width: 320px;
    }
    #nav ul:after {
        margin-left: 100%;
        content: "";
    }
    #nav ul li {
        display: inline;
    }
    #nav a:link {
            border-bottom: 0;
        }
    #nav a:hover {
            color: #f00;
        }
```

The markup and code work fine in Firefox 50. I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150294/how-can-i-keep-my-last-horizontal-nav-item-from-wrapping-to-the-next-line) but it is not clear how the answer might be applied to my problem.

Comment: For what you define the :after element? If you add overflow:hidden to the ul, does this fix your layout problem?

Comment: Thanks. Without the `:after`, the navbar items don't get spaced out to take up the whole 320px. Adding `overflow:hidden` didn't fix the problem.

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/znna5b8f/

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/rrjh4g2L/

If you set fixed width for `#nav ul` and you know that you always will have only 4 items in the menu, just set `width: 25%;` for `li` elements and use `float: left;`

```
ul { width: 320px; overflow: hidden; } /* or use clearfix hack if you want */
li { width: 25%; float: left; }
```

It should render correctly across all browsers.