# How can the dropdown menus in a page be zoomed in a page?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page in which the body of the page is zoomed as below:

```
body {
    background: #E0D5B7 url(img/page_bg.jpg) repeat-x;
    margin:auto;
    width:1000px;
    padding-top:100px;
    zoom: 1.165; -moz-transform: scale(1.165);
}
```

However because the drop-down menus are not re-sized(zoomed) it is difficult to make a correct selection. For eg: if a user selects value at index 5 it takes the value at index 3 because the drop down is not zoomed in accordance to the body. How I can do this? Is there any other way by which this can be accomplished?

Below is a drop-down menu I have for the page.

```
<tr id="sped-limit">
    <td height="70">
        <label>Speed Limit (mph)</label>
        <br>
        <div class="drop-down">
        <select id="Drop-Down-Speed" name="Speed Limit Selection">
        <option >Select Speed</option>
        <option>25</option>
        <option>30</option>
        <option>35</option>
        <option>40</option>
        <option>45</option>
        <option>50</option>
        <option>55</option>
        </select></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I don't have an answer but I do have a question, why would you zoom the page rather than just designing it bigger? I really don't understand the purpose of doing that at all.

Answer (score 0):

since the menu is text why dont you create an option to make the text bigger as well
[auto resize text (font size) when resizing window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989950/auto-resize-text-font-size-when-resizing-window)