# jQuery text resize issue

Tags: jquery, css

I am attempting to loop through some span's of text and resize the text to fit within its containing div based on the smallest font size required to do so.

```
<div id="preview">        
        <div id="test">
            <section class="slide">
                <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br />
                Nam in mauris a magna elementum ornare vel at velit.<br />
                Nulla facilisi.<br />
                Sed eu odio id urna fermentum imperdiet eget sit amet enim.</span>
            </section>

            <section class="slide">
                <span>Cras cursus ante et tortor placerat sodales.<br />
                Curabitur libero quam, cursus sit amet feugiat id, elementum at lectus.<br />
                Integer volutpat aliquet massa at adipiscing.<br />
                Vivamus purus leo</span>
            </section>
         </div><!--/ #test -->
    </div><!--/ #preview -->
```

My jquery I have to do this so far is

```
var fontSizeArray = [];

$('#test > .slide').children('span').each(function () {
    var currentFontSize = parseInt($(this).css('font-size'));
    do {
        currentFontSize = currentFontSize + 1;
        $(this).css('font-size', currentFontSize);            
    } while ($(this).width() < $('#test').width());
    fontSizeArray.push(currentFontSize);
});

var smallest = Math.min.apply( null, fontSizeArray );      

$('#test > .slide').children('span').each(function () {
    $(this).css('font-size', smallest);
});​
```

I have created a fiddle to better illustrate this.

http://jsfiddle.net/H7nrY/4/

Basically all of the text should be resized to fit within the div #test

Comment: Should all the `span`s have the *same* `font-size` (so you're constrained by the `font-size` of the longest line of text)? Or is each `span` sized individually? Is the `font-size` limited by the vertical height of the parent `div` element, or is the `div` allowed to expand vertically?

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes all the spans should have the same font size. And yes font size will be limited by the vertical height as well on a per span basis. Was just trying to get the width sorted then I was going to look at the height. But if you have a solution for both...

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989950/auto-resize-text-font-size-when-resizing-window Also take a look here, there may be somehting to do what you need: http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/jquery-plugins-typography/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a conditional after the loop that checks if you've gone too far:

```
if ($(this).width() > $("#test").width()) {
   currentFontSize--;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H7nrY/5/

Comment: beat me to that - the problem with the while loop is, based on the logic, it will not exit until you have gone too far, so you would have to step down to the last font.

Comment: @Kmfk Anyway to build this into the logic for the loop or does it need to be seperate?

Comment: @Stephen Possibly, but it still seems easier to just decrement the `currentFontSize` after the loop exits. You know the loop exited because the span is now larger than you want, which tells you the previous font was the upper bounds.