# Elastic Squares (CSS HTML)

Tags: css, html, web, responsive-design

I'm trying to build an 'elastic' website in CSS and HTML; I want there to be 6 squares along the width of the screen; I have the width of the squares scaling to the screen size, but I want to keep my squares square. Is there any way I can set the height of my div's to the same size as the div width (which is being set off of a % value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bwDa9/embedded/result/).

Basically, give the element the same value for the `width` and `padding-bottom` so that it will stay as a square as you scale the page.

```css
.square {
    background-color: red;
    width:15%;
    height:0px;
    padding-bottom:15%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Read more about fluid squares [here](http://dinosaurswithlaserz.com/2011/07/18/fluid-squares-v2/).

Comment: That will only work if you don't have any content. With my solution you just have to relatively position the square and absolutely position the content.

Comment: @A.M.K It works with contents as well. Check the [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bwDa9/embedded/result/).

Comment: OK, I stand corrected, that's better than absolutely positioning the content.

Comment: I have a paragraph and header in my div, i'm sorting a jsfiddle now

Comment: @user2344348 What does it mean by "break"? See http://jsfiddle.net/3kCwM/18/embedded/result/

Comment: @Antony The smaller text doesn't stay in the square

Comment: @user2344348 You are having a square that is reducing in size and there couldn't be enough screen real estate to accommodate the fixed size text. You are asking a different question here. Your original question was to have the squares that will resize with the window and I have answered it in good faith. Now you want to have the text that resize as well. If you are having a different question consider looking for [an existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989950/auto-resize-text-font-size-when-resizing-window) or ask a new question if it doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: @Antony Sorry for the confusion,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the most common solution is to use a 1px by 1px image and make it full width with a variable height:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/57xhg/1/

CSS:

```
.wrap {
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100px;
}

.wrap img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using background-repeat-x and background-repeat-y property by providing the elastic line you want to draw