# Responsive text size using ems

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, font-size

I am trying to learn some responsive webdesign techniques and trying to code my website in a responsive way. I don't want to use any frameworks yet. My problem is that div width in ems is different on mobile than on desktops. When viewing on a desktop, my `h1` fits into a div and on mobile it does not. Shouldn't this be the same in both case? All sizes are in em.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]>               <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en" > <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en" > <!--<![endif]-->

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Sieć z pasją</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!-- Google webfonts -->
    <!-- font-family: 'Expletus Sans', cursive; -->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Expletus+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="transparent-bg">
        <h1><span class="hello">Hello</span>
        </br><span class="is">my name is</span>
        </br><span class="adam">Adam</span></h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background:url('../img/background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
.transparent-bg {
    background-color:rgba(185,178,160,0.6);
    padding:2em;
    padding-top:5em;
    max-width:30em;
    position:relative;
    left:4em;
    top:5em;
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'Expletus Sans', cursive;
    color:black;    
    line-height:1em;
}
    span.hello {
        font-size:4em;
    }
    span.is {
        letter-spacing:0.4em;
        position:relative;
        left:0.3em;
    }
    span.adam {
        font-size:3em;
        letter-spacing:0.15em;
        position:relative;
        top:0.3em;
    }
```

Here is a live version: [adamlakomy.pl](http://www.adamlakomy.pl). I appreciate all your help.

[image: mobile version]

Comment: Have you tried using [`@media` queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) to resize the mobile `em` size?

Comment: isnt the purpose of em is to be proportional? I obviusly dont know sth very important..

Comment: I think part of your problem simply is due to a non-perfect understanding of `em`. Check out [this link](http://www.impressivewebs.com/understanding-em-units-css/) for more info. on it. As for your project specifically, is the left positioning of the text where you want it to be? Or is it a positioning issue, not a font size one?

Comment: positioning is intended.

Comment: This problem can be exemplified on your computer as well if you make your browser small. The thing is the `em`s don't automatically change themselves to be small or large to fit the window - they have to be told to do so by `@media` queries or javascript. That's your main problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the text sizes are not re-sizing based on the window. [Here is a great article](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/how_we_learned_to_leave_body_font_size_alone/) to help you understand responsive re-sizing.

To fix this you have a few options.

The first is to use `@media` queries - you can even still use `em`s! **Note**: when using `em`s you should have a base `em` that all others (including width, height, and other font sizes) are based off of. You can then affect everything by changing that one font size. For example

```
media all and (max-width: 25em) {
  html {
    font-size:50%;
  }
}
```

This would make all the text you have half it's original size when the screen is smaller than `25em` width

A second option would be to use javascript (this uses jQuery as well) to do it. I quickly pulled this example from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989950/auto-resize-text-font-size-when-resizing-window), you can probably find or come up with a more eloquent solution if you want to use this method. Here is that example

```
$(function() {
    $(window).bind('resize', function()
    {
        resizeMe();
        }).trigger('resize');
});
function resizeMe() {
    //Standard height, for which the body font size is correct
    var preferredHeight = 768;  

    var displayHeight = $(window).height();
    var percentage = displayHeight / preferredHeight;
    var newFontSize = Math.floor(/*default font size*/ * percentage) - 1;
     $("body").css("font-size", newFontSize);
}
```

Or you could use a plugin which I don't recommend for paragraphs of text, but for your small amount they would work fine. Two of the most common ones are [**FitText**](http://fittextjs.com/) and [**BigText**](http://www.zachleat.com/web/bigtext-makes-text-big/)