# CSS - Text is moving from bar when resolution is changing

Tags: html, css

when i change resolution of my display text on my top bar is changing
Can somebody help me to fix it?

Normaly:
http://funedit.com/imgedit/soubory/small_10348459921396544905.jpg?x

With changed resolution, or with smaller borowser window:
http://funedit.com/imgedit/soubory/small_19550755301396544822.jpg

My Html:

```
<body> 
 <div class="top-panel">
    <div id="center"> <a class="top-button" href="#"></a>
       <span class="text">Prave hraje <b>5000</b> hracov na <b>150</b> serveroch!</span>
       <span class="panel">Registruj sa zdarma nebo</span>
        <input type="text">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="image" id="login-button" src="images/login_button.png" alt="Submit">
        <div class="warningimg"></div><div class="warning"> NIGHT CUP 2014 - Sledujte priamy prenos! </div>
       <div class="main"> 
        <div class="logobg">
        <a class="logo" href="#"></a>
          <input class="searchinput" type="text">
          <input class="searchsubmit" type="image">
        <div class="news"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </body>
```

My CSS:

```
body {
    background-image:url('images/background.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color:#cccccc;
    background-size 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    position: relative;
    background-position: 50% 0;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
#center {
    width: 1030px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*display: inline-block; */
}
.top-panel {
    background-image: url("images/top_panel.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: center;
    height: 43px;
    padding-top:5px;
    display: block;
}
a.top-button {
    background-image: url("images/top_button.png");
    height: 37px;
    width: 141px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.text {
    color: #9c9c9c;
    padding: 0px 10px;
}
.panel {
    color: #6ab1ed;
    padding: 0px 390px;
}
input{
    vertical-align:top;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 21px;
    width: 97px;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative; left: 550px; top: 4px;
}
span{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: center;    
}
span b{
    font-weight:bold;
}
#login-button{
    /*background-image: url("images/login_button.png");   uz je to v HTML*/
    height: 27px;
    width: 81px;
    line-height: 27px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; left: 550px; top: 4px; 
}
```

If somebody want to see the site LIVE its here: funedit.com/andurit/new/

Thank you all for reading this:)

Comment: I am speaking about that BLUE TEXT "Registruj sa zdarma nebo"

Comment: USE BIGTEXT inbuilt plugin refer my post below for more methods.

Comment: There are many answers here that seem to have helped you, the rule here is to at least upvote the ones that helped you with your issue and to accept (by clicking ont hte tick) the one you find the best. You will learn much more about stackoverflow by having a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a quick fix would be:

```css
.panel {
    color: #6AB1ED;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 0 390px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Cool man its really working, can u explain why ? :P beause i really dont know :P

Btw if u open my site in mobile device it do some shit on right up corner, dont u know how to fix it? Its not doing in PC borowser

Comment: because you are using  a huge padding (which is not good, you should consider @john Tobin 's Answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/22844652/3448527 - and arrange your Nav items into floated divs or list-items)

So as you have defined span with display:inline-block, it is better to give it a width otherwise it will be 100%, and the line-height:1 it is to get the line-height to default since you define in your span line-height:35px.

Comment: I looked it up and problem seems to be the body. try to change: margin:0 auto; to margin:0; and remove min-width.

Comment: Its not working, but min-width: 1160px; work correctly, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

`span {line-height: 35px}` is the reason for the big line spacing; and an absence of `white-space: nowrap;` is why it's breaking into lines. However, the main problem is that, when resized, there simply isn't enough space for all that stuff. This is due to the massive padding left and right of the `.panel`. Rather than use padding to position the item, you should try to arrange your nav items through floated divs, or text-align.

Answer (score 0):

Set the min-width to something like:

```
.panel {
    color: #6ab1ed;
    padding: 0px 390px;
    min-width: 160px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Wvh7/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.panel {
    color: #6AB1ED;
    padding: 0 350px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U can decide font size for different window size.Actually problem is when u resize size of text is remaining same and hence overflowing hence u can change below font-size:  parameter according to ur need.This also works for mobile screen also.

```
@media all and (min-width: 400px) {
    .panel {
        font-size: 8px;
    }
}
@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
    .panel {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
```

> Or

u can use jquery resize function for whole page refer this [auto resize text (font size) when resizing window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989950/auto-resize-text-font-size-when-resizing-window)

> OR

Directly use inbuilt  jQuery plugin like FitText (http://fittextjs.com/). It automatically sizes text to fit the width of the parent element.

Another jQuery plugin with the same goal is BigText(http://www.zachleat.com/web/bigtext-makes-text-big/).

> DEMO bigtext

```
<div id="bigtext" style="width: 300px">
    <div>The elusive</div>
    <div>BIGTEXT</div>
    <div>plugin exclusively</div>
    <div>captured on film</div>
</div>

$('#bigtext').bigtext();
```

As u can see u just have to call a small function full implementation is in there website its just small snippet there are lot of use of that.