# How to resize text based on browser window size

Tags: html, css, text, resize

I would like to know how to set the size of text based on the browser window. My current code for my piece of text:

```
#quoteField{
letter-spacing:5px;
position:relative;
top:20%;
left:10%;
xtop:325px;
xleft:200px;
font-size:50px;

line-height:20px;
width:500;

color:#ffffff;
}

.quote{
font-family: Merriweather, serif;
}

.quoteHeavier{
font-family: Merriweather, serif;
font-weight:600;
}
```

Alternatively, you could check out this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ez3Zs/1/).

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989950/auto-resize-text-font-size-when-resizing-window?rq=1

Comment: Use `em` to size your text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try with css property `font-size: 4vw;` where you can learn about [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)

Comment: A quick and simple solution, I didn't expect it to be so simple. Thanks!

Comment: Simple is my second name! Happy to help ;o)

Comment: Cool solution. Please note the browser computability for this solution: http://caniuse.com/viewport-units

Comment: @Stasel Nice tip. But I guess his background video would be broken too when viewport units are :o)